# How to show only specific directory to FTP user

Tags: ftp, file-sharing

In my ubuntu 14.04 I installed the ([FTPD](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ftpd/0.17-31)) ftp server. I would like to create one user for that and set nologin to that user. When logging on using an FTP client, I want that particular user to be able to see the entire system directory.

*How do I restrict one user like that to one directory (E.g. `/usr/local/example`)?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `vsftpd` (*“Very Secure File Transfer Protocol Daemon”*), the configuration is exceedingly simple:

```
sudo apt-get install vsftpd
```

then:

```
sudo nano /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

ensure you have the following parameters set right:

```
# Depending on the version you're running, you might want to set the following 
# parameter to YES 
# (if affected by https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vsftpd/+bug/1313450)
listen=YES
# to allow local users to log on:
local_enable=YES
#if you want write access too:
write_enable=YES
# Set anonymous user directory to /srv/ftp (no default)
anon_root=/srv/ftp
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES

# following for debugging purposes (to ensure you're on the right server)
ftpd_banner=Welcome to Aravind's FTP service.

# Now restrict users to their home directories:
chroot_local_user=YES
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

And now, if you want to set a particular user to a particular directory, just create a user with a particular directory:

```
sudo adduser ftpuser --home /usr/local/example
```

**To test:**

Go to a terminal on the machine running `vsftpd` and type: `ftp 127.0.0.1` and if you're greeted by your own banner, `vsftpd` works!

Then test on the same machine to its public address: `ftp 1.2.3.4` and finally from a remote machine to the public address.  If something goes wrong with the public addresses, check your firewall settings.

**Additional notes:**

If you don't want the user to log on, add the `--shell /bin/false` parameter to the `adduser` command.

You might also want to delete all the directories/files (`Desktop`, `Pictures`, ... that the `adduser` created if you don't want them there...

### Done!

Comment: Even after this, I am able to view other users home directory and all the contents in it :(

Comment: @DaveRanjan:  Try again... c I went over my answer and cannot find any holes or [Ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), refer to this one and post any errors you encountered along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you need to use that specific FTP server software? What you're looking for is mostly called "chroot" (*ch*ange the *root* directory per user) or something similar. According to [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=311339#5) the netkit ftp server, that's contained in the `linux-ftpd` package, doesn't offer that feature. Event the [launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ftpd/0.17-31) says

> This is the netkit ftp server. It is recommended for you to use one of its
>    alternatives, such as wu-ftpd or proftpd.

I know from experience that pure-ftpd (setting `VIRTUALCHROOT`) and ProFTPd (by [virtual hosts](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/faq/linked/faq-ch5.html#AEN524)) offer the feature you're looking for. Both are available from the standard Ubuntu repositories. Other ftp server software probably offers similar features.